# Calculate the integral of inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have a following problem: Let f be a smooth function, and $y=f(x)$. Do we have some method to calculate (may be approximately) the following function $$F(y)=\int x(y)dy \quad ?$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Young's inequality is along these lines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions

Answer (score 2):

$$z=x(y) \implies y=f(z) \implies dy = f'(z) dz$$

Then

$$F(y) = \int dz \, z f'(z)$$

We can then use integration by parts:

$$F(y) = z f(z) - \int dz \, f(z) = y \, x(y) - \int dz \, f(z)$$

This is about as simple a form as you'll get without further details.